# Execute command wait for it to complete, sending a live output in Go

Tags: go, exec, binaryfiles

I've got a binary file that loops forever, returning an output every millisecond (scary, I know). I'd  like to invoke it through Go. The problem is, (as far as I see & understand), Go will wait for the command to complete before showing the output. In my case, the command *will not complete* until killed (I'd also like to stop the binary by stopping the Go program). Here is what I've got:

```golang
func main(){
  loggerInit := exec.Command("/logger")
  var out Bytes.Buffer
  loggerInit.Stdout = &out
  err = loggerInit.Run()
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }
  fmt.Printf(out.String())
}
```

But this produces no output and stays in the command forever (while actually running `/logger` by hand does give desired output). Thanks, and cheers!

Comment: Assign os.Stdout to loggerInit.Stdout, not a buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You're using [`Run`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Run):

> Run starts the specified command and waits for it to complete.

Where, based on your description, you should be using [`Start`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Start):

> Start starts the specified command but does not wait for it to complete.

But of course, you'll need to adjust your code to wait or loop or something, otherwise your application will simply exit immediately after the first time it reads any output.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion, but using Start just ended the program. I will definitely try with some wait at the end though!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can pipe logger's output with Go using this command

```
./logger | main.go
```

This mean, the logger produces the something (eg. bytes/string) and Go read that output as an input.

main.go

```
buf := make([]byte, expectedBytes)
for {
    bytes, _ := io.ReadFull(os.Stdin, buf)
    // do it here
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
}
```

Sorry for my English and hope it help.

Comment: Thank you for the info, and your English is fine! In `// do it here`, what are the exact commands I should place? Not sure how it should handle stdout, so wondering ;))

Comment: You can print out the logger's output like this `fmt.Println(string(bytes))`